# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I get this error `cannot read property 'Value' of undefined` , what am i doing wrong?

```
years: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 1970; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++)
    {
        this.years.push({'Value': i});
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you get the Value from object. The exception should show you the line where error happen.

Comment: @jcubic, that's all, i want to create an object and use like this `year.Value`

Comment: this line look weird `years: any[] = [];` it should be var `years = [];` or `years: [],` if it's inside object.

Comment: @jcubic this is an angular2/typescript initialization of typed array. The line is correct AFAIK.

Comment: @BorisShchegolev didn't notice that the question have tag typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cannot read property 'Value' of undefined

clearly you are trying to use `.Value` on something that does have it. e.g.

```
this.years.push({'Value': i});
let year = undefined;
year.Value; // BANG
```

Probably you want something like:

```
this.years.push({'Value': i});
let year = this.years[0];
year.Value; // Okay
```